# MySQL: Grouping and counting multiple occurences, then only display the highest amount per individual combination

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm currently trying to determine which user owns which PC in my company.
We're logging every login activity in a MySQL table.

Now we only have information about which User is using which client, but given that users may also use other machines, I need to check which user has the highest amount of logins on that specific machine.

```
Table: log
+----+-----------+------+----------------+
| ID |  Client   | user |   timestamp    | 
+----+-----------+------+----------------+
|  1 | hostnamea | ab   | xx.xx.xx xx:xx |
|  2 | hostnameb | cd   | xx.xx.xx xx:xx |
|  3 | hostnameb | ab   | xx.xx.xx xx:xx |
|  4 | hostnameb | ab   | xx.xx.xx xx:xx |
|  5 | hostnamec | ab   | xx.xx.xx xx:xx |
|  6 | hostnamec | ef   | xx.xx.xx xx:xx |
|  7 | hostnamec | ef   | xx.xx.xx xx:xx |
+----+-----------+------+----------------+
(timestamp is actually unimportant,
 but maybe someone has an awesome optimization idea which includes the timestamp,
 so I leave it here)
```

In this case, hostname user "ef" becomes owner of "hostnamec"

I already got so far that I can display a "top logins" list:

```
SELECT `user`, `client`, COUNT(*) logins 
FROM `log` 
WHERE `client` LIKE '_%' AND timestamp > "2016-09-00 00:00:00"  # (filter out garbage and old machines)
GROUP BY `client, `user`
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10     (If there are less than 10 logins, the machine isn't being used anyways)
ORDER BY `user`;
```

This returns user, client and a number of logins, which, I hope, specify how often a specific user logged into a machine.

I don't really know how to access and use the extra "logins" row generated by the count.

My goal is something like this:

```
+-----------+------+
|  Client   | user |
+-----------+------+
| hostnamea | ab   | (1xab, nothing else: ab wins)
| hostnameb | ab   | (2x ab,1x cd: ab wins)
| hostnamec | ef   | (2x ef, 1x ab: ef wins)
+-----------+------+
```

My next step would be an Update on another existing table that has hostnames, but it's missing users

```
UPDATE hosts
INNER JOIN query(output of first query) USING (client)
SET hosts.user = query.user
```

(If that makes sense)

Can anyone assist me in my first query?
I already found some solutions including Oracle functions, or tables that are slightly diffently designed.

It's been long time since I had to do more than simple Selects, updates and inserts with SQL; to be honest, I got kinda confused by what I found, so I'm asking my own question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by filtering in the `where` clause.  Here is one way:

```
select l.*
from log l
where l.timestamp = (select max(l2.timestamp) 
                     from log l2
                     where l2.user = l.user
                    );
```

This is easily generalizable to get the owner as of any given date:

```
select l.*
from log l
where l.timestamp = (select max(l2.timestamp) 
                     from log l2
                     where l2.timestamp <= $AsOfDate and l2.user = l.user
                    );
```

Comment: I'm trying to almost completely ignore the timestamp, because there could always be someone logged in to the machine, who is not the original owner.

Logins may occure multiple times in the log table, I want to filter out which login (user + client combination) occured the most and use the user as new owner of client.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT
   Client 
 , SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(user ORDER BY Client DESC), ',', 1) user
FROM 
 log
GROUP BY 
 Client
ORDER BY 
 Client ASC
```

Comment: Thanks so far!

But this gives me just the last entry of every login.
I already thought about that, this way, I could also use the timestamp to determine the user.

I could just live with that, but we have many users that work on PC's that don't actually belong to them.

So I'm trying to use the fictional value "number_of_logins" to determine which user gets to be the owner of the machine